# Complex matrix exponential with Armadillo library

Tags: c++, matrix, physics, armadillo

I'm doing some physics simulation in C++ using Armadillo. I need to calculate a product looking like:

```
Q = R * exp(neg_i*Lambda*t) * R.t() * Q
```

Where Q,R are cx_mat class of the same size, Lambda is a mat class of the same size as  Q,R and is diagonal, neg_i is -i the complex number and t is a double. I should get a unitary matrix  as a solution but what I'm getting is non unitary. I was wondering if the exponential function works well with complex matrices? or if not what should I replace it with?

Comment: It would help to include a minimal working example of code that exhibits the problem you are having.

Comment: My question is mainly concerning if the Armadillo library can handle the exponential of a complex matrix. What I'll be doing after is calculating
```
norm(Q*Q.t() - id)
```
Where id is the identity matrix with the same size as the other ones. This is the check for unitarity and should give something very close to zero (I've used it for other checks and it works) but it's giving something large. I just want to see if the exponential is the source of the problem.

Comment: @YusufKasim Maybe there is confusion here between [expmat()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#expmat) and [exp()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#misc_fns). Matrix exponential is done by `expmat()`, while element-wise exponential is `exp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [**expmat()**](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#expmat) function for a matrix exponential, [exp()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#misc_fns) calculates an element-wise exponential.

For example, some code I'm currently using for a physics simulation:

```cpp
arma::cx_mat f;  // A hermitian matrix
double delta_t ;  // A time step
std::complex<double> i_imag(0.0,1.0) ;  // i, the imaginary number

std::vector<arma::cx_mat> U; // A vector of complex unitary matrices.

U.push_back(arma::expmat(-i_imag * delta_t * f));
```

Have tested this code, taking the matrix exponential of anti-hermitian matrices to get unitary transformation and works fine.